# iOS App Extensions: Share or Action?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I wonder if the new iOS App Extensions feature supports my case? If so, would I use `Share` or `Action`?

My case is similar to a `Share` but not really sharing, just making request of my service. Here's the use case:

1. From an item in a host app, the user taps the button for my extension, which the app developer has placed there
2. The host app opens my extension passing a couple of bits of relevant data from the item the user was on
3. Check if the user is authorized to use my API (has API auth token)
4. If authorized, present a very simple form (probably two select lists) with Submit and Cancel buttons. No content or text editing
5. Upon submit, post to my API and receive a response that the request was accepted or an error with validation details. Upon errors, ask the user to try again or cancel. Upon success, return to the host app
6. If not authorized, ask if they are already a member of my service
7. If already a member, present a login form and perform authorization over the API, storing the auth token that is returned, then proceeding to step #4
8. If not a member, present a signup form asking for email and some minimal setup choices, storing an auth token, then proceeding to step #4

Comment: So what did you do in the end?

Comment: @momo The way to go is with an Action. I asked a more detailed question and later answered it myself here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300194/ios-app-extension-action-custom-data/27044250#27044250